# I am trying visualise railway track from shape shapes in python

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, plotly-python, shapely

I am trying to visualise railway tracks using Plotly lines on a map. I am a beginner who is working on gis data and visualise railway networks. i am not sure about the approach i am going about and i don't want to use arcgis or qgis.

Problem: I am not sure what should be added in the names attribute.
it would great i could get an overview of the code where i am going wrong

zipfile contains the .shp,.dbf.shx,.prj,.cpj

The error i am getting is 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
this the code which i am working on.

```
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
import wget

geo_df = gpd.read_file(r'railwaytrack.zip' )

lattiudes = [47.04691]
longitudes = [8.37467]
names=[ ]

for feature, line_geo in zip(geo_df.geometry, geo_df.name):
    if isinstance(feature, shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString):
        linestrings = [feature]
    elif isinstance(feature, shapely.geometry.multilinestring.MultiLineString):
        linestrings = feature.geoms
    else:
        continue
    for linestring in linestrings:
        x, y = linestring.xy
        lattiudes  = np.append(lattiudes, y)
        longitudes = np.append(longitudes, x)
        names = np.append(names, [name]*len(y))
        lattiudes  = np.append(lattiudes, None)
        longitudes = np.append(longitudes, None)
        names = np.append(names, None)

fig = px.line_geo(lat=lattiudes, lon=longitudes)
fig.show()
```

Comment: You have probably customized it by referring to this [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/#lines-on-maps-from-geopandas). The name attribute is the name of the river, so your data should contain the name of the route. The name attribute is the name of the river, so your data should contain the name of the route. Also, there is an initial value for the initial latitude and longitude, what does this mean?

Comment: latitude and longitude values of place where the shapefiles will be plotted

Comment: `name` is not a column in the shapefiles attribute table

Comment: @PaulH what does name specify then?

Comment: nothing. it doesn't exist. that's why you're getting that error